# Interactive vertical line drawing in python tkinter / canvas / subplot

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've built a Python GUI using tkinter and basically it looks like below.

[image]

And now I want to add some diagnostics lines at the point where I click which expand dashed lines to all subplots like below.

[image]

While I can manually bind click events and link it to `canvas.clear()`, `canvas.draw()` stuffs to re-generate the plots in the subplots including the desired vertical lines, I believe there exists some navigation module which has this functionality already (since this kind of functionality is supported on so many figure-related application including MATLAB, Origin, and so on).

Can anybody tell me some handy way to include this functionality in tkinter? Or really should I build it manually??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not completely understand the question but i thought that you want to bind the mouse or keyboard event in canvas.

This link may help you
[Tkinter events binding](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: Of course I can myself bind mouse events in canvas, but you know, for example in Origin, if one plots a figure, Origin automatically draws a marker and vertical/horizontal lines at where the user clicks. Doesn't plt.subplot has such built-in navigator?

Comment: "Doesn't plt.subplot has such built-in navigator?" 
- I don't know well about that but
I had an idea to draw the vertical/horizontal lines at where the user clicks. Firstly get the width and height of the window and if i click on point(x,y) then by using canvas.draw() draw then line in that window.
Like as if i click on the point(500,200) and window size is (1000,1000) then for horizontal draw in (500+1000) and for vertical (200+1000).

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than an answer, would recommend deleting and positng as a comment